# Windows 8 Phone sample app to play / stop an audio file

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

Where can I find a simple audio player code sample for a Windows 8 Phone app ?

I am new to Windows 8 Phone development and was trying out to make an app that simply plays audio files. Being new to XAML and this Windows 8 Phone SDK, I find it very difficult in understanding where to start about from.

I tried searching for sample project from here : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/

But couldn't understand which project does what.

Can somebody please direct me to a sample project and simply does the following

- Play audio
- Pause audio
- Stop audio

these audio files will be locally be added to the solution.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Beginners for how to Media player using the Silverlight on Windows Phone](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Beginners-for-how-to-Media-1ec0eaf0)